# Unexpected DO-WHILE behavior: Is it ignoring the expression?

Tags: c++

I have some C++ homework but have been stuck by some unexpected behavior. The following code is a piece from the program in question:

```
void tenderMoney(Candy& _Candy, CoinCount& _Coins){

const double amountToPay = _Candy._Price;
int coinTendered = 0;
double totalTendered = 0;

do {
    cout << "Insert a coin: ";

    if (cin >> coinTendered){

        switch (coinTendered){
        case 5: {
            totalTendered += 0.05;
            _Coins._Nickels++;
            break;
        }
        case 10: {
            totalTendered += 0.10;
            _Coins._Dimes++;
            break;
        }
        case 25: {
            totalTendered += 0.25;
            _Coins._Quarters++;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid coin. ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
    }
  } while (totalTendered < amountToPay);
}
```

This works as intended for all coins but the .05 cents. It asks for an extra coin even when `(totalTendered < amountToPay)` evaluates to equal values. Anyone that can shed some light on what my issue might be?

Note: The objects are being referenced from their respective `vector` containers. Feel free to request any additional code you might think is relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are being bit by *floating point rounding errors*. Use an `int` to keep track of the number of *cents*, rather than using a `double` to keep track of dollars.

In more detail, the problem is that the value 0.05 can't be represented exactly in binary floating point. It might really be 0.0499999999999, which isn't exactly what you want. When you compare this to your target value, the comparison goes "yep, that is less" even thought it might be just 0.0000000000001 cent less.

Comment: So, based on that, the coins that work simply do so because they are slightly greater than the `amountToPay`?

Comment: Right, your other coins might be a little more or a little less than the exact amount you want. You definitely want to work with integer numbers of cents here, and these problems will go away.